# How to create multi-column indexes with jsonb colum and int column

Tags: postgresql

Table:

```
create table posts(doc jsonb, timeline int);
insert into posts values('{"body":"aaa", "tags":["tag1","tag2"]}', 1572192887);
insert into posts values('{"body":"aaa", "tags":["tag12","tag23"]}', 1572192888);
```

Now I want to create an index to make the following query fast:

```
select * from posts 
where doc->'tags' ?| array['tag1','tag3','tag10'] 
order by timeline desc limit 10
```

I have tried to use the following index but it doesn't work. My query get only `50` qps. (table size is only `20000` rows). But if remove the `order by created desc`, I get `500` qps.

```
create index on test_tags using gin((doc->'tags'),timeline);
```

Index created successfully. but still got low qps.

So how can I make the index?

Comment: RUM indexes (https://github.com/postgrespro/rum) might have a solution for you, though I don't know exactly how to deploy it in your case.

Comment: Your example data does give us the flavor of the situation, but isn't sufficient to analyze index performance.  Please give us "EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)" of the query against realistic data sizes.

Comment: @jjanes I have said the example index "doen't work". You don't need waste time to debug it.

Comment: @jjanes then you should explain what you mean "it works for me". I clearly said it got low qps with "order by" added.

Comment: Multicolumn indexes just do not work that way. Read in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) what can you expect of them.

Comment: Sure.  the index is used, and it sped up the query a lot.  It didn't do away with the sort, but reduced the set of the data to be sorted to the point it was very fast.  Obviously this was with my simulated data, as I don't have access to yours.  Maybe you can't share your data, but can at least share an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS).

Comment: @jjanes You are talking about single-column index. My question is about multi-column index. Please read the question details again.

Comment: @klin I know my indexes method is wrong, and the document doesn't mention json array. that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Multicolumn indexes do not work like that regardless of column types. Basically, a two-column index makes sense when a particular value can appear multiple times in the first column with different values in the second. Then the index part of the second column might be used when you are searching for a specific value of the first one. This is not the case described in the question.

Comment: @klin Yes I have tested and you are right. I shall edit my question. BTW, Mongodb is doing this very well, their Multicolumn indexes works fast for this kind of `order by` query.